# Individual ID for many buttons from forEach loop for toggle using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, toggle

Im generating many buttons from forEach loop.

```
examples.forEach((ex, i) => {const button = document.createElement("button");
      button.classList.add("toggle");
      button.innerHTML = "výsledek";
      button.addEventListener("click", () => toggle(i));
      card.appendChild(button);
});
```

I need add specific ID to each button. I think i could use the "i" and use it for toggle effect.

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
  $(".toggle").toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

I want have for every button individual toggle effect like open/close but at this moment i use class "toggle" so all buttons interact on click. I need individual interaction for each button

Best :)

Comment: _"I need add specific ID to each button"_ - No you don't ([What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/)) -> `this` in the event handler is the clicked button (DOM node)

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery with plain old JS/DOM methods?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the element itself in the loop. You could also consider event delegation.

```js
button.addEventListener("click", () => button.classList.toggle("clicked"));
```